# why `tasklist | find "cmd.exe"` doesn't work on win7 but xp and vista?

Tags: windows-7, grep, find

Hi I run `tasklist | find "cmd.exe"` but has different result on the following OS:

- winXP: get the cmd.exe process success
- Vista: get the cmd.exe process success
- win7:  find: cmd.exe: No such file or directory, but `tasklist | grep "cmd.exe"`  the command `grep` works for it.

Anyone has idea why win7 use `grep` instead of `find`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It works here. This is what I get in Windows 7 x64:

```
C:\Users\me>tasklist | find "cmd.exe"
cmd.exe                       7456 Console                    1      3,544 K
```

Of course, this is only going to work for certain if ran from the console. It requires that `cmd.exe` must first be running.

Answer (score 0):

When running a cygwin based bash shell rather than a cmd shell on Windows, the find command that is in the path is the UNIX-like find command.
It looks for a path "cmd.exe" which of course isn't found; instead of searching for a string To run the Windows find command you would need to use the full path to it.

You can see which find commands are present using the Windows "which" command.
This is the output in a cygwin shell:

```
$where find
C:\cygwin\bin\find.exe
C:\Windows\System32\find.exe
```

and this is what it shows in a Windows cmd shell:

```
C:\>where find
C:\Windows\System32\find.exe
```

Not sure if this is your exact problem, but you mentioned grep, so I thought you might also be using cygwin, or something similar (although I am aware that Microsoft also have a native grep clone included with some of their build tools).